# I'm trying to only get one row from a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Temp ordering table

```
temp_id     series_id   news_ticket_breakdown_id    quantity    expiry_time
58db09bba25b4   2                  2                     2       1490750973
58db09bba25b4   2                  4                     1      1490750973
```

NEWS ITEMS TABLE

```
news_id   series_id      news_title
   26          2         GENERIC TICKETING
   27          2         GENERIC TICKETING
```

When I do a left join on series_id I get back 4 rows and I only want 2. I'm not sure how to limit the amount of joined rows to one row.

CURRENT QUERY

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    ticket_ordering_temp    
LEFT JOIN 
    news_items 
on 
    ( news_items.series_id = SELECT 
                                DISTINCT(event_id)
                             FROM 
                                news_items 
                             where 
                                series_id=ticket_ordering_temp.series_id
    )
where 
    temp_id='58db09bba25b4''
```

DESIRED RESULT
I want just 1 row from table 2 and not 2 rows joined as stated above

```
temp_id     series_id   news_ticket_breakdown_id    quantity    expiry_time news_title
58db09bba25b4   2                  2                     2       1490750973  GENERIC TICKETING
58db09bba25b4   2                  4                     1      1490750973 GENERIC TICKETING
```

Comment: what is your `JOIN` condition?

Comment: I don't see `event_id` mentioned in either table definition, or in the sample data.

Comment: Why are you attempting to do a left join as opposed to a join?

Comment: becuse I need all the left table stuff even if second table exists.

Comment: updated the query...

Comment: This would be easy in a modern db engine via a lateral join/apply, which have been part of the ansi standard since sql:1999. Sadly, MySql isn't really a modern db engine any more. It's lagged behind for more than a decade now and hasn't advanced alongside the other major players.

Comment: You need to specify exactly what you want it to return. What would be your desired result? Two rows from Temp ordering table or the two from NEWS ITEMS TABLE? Or is it two from one plus a column that is in another? You see, you need to be a bit clear with what your result should look like so we can help

Comment: Try "Select series_id,news_title From news_items Group By series_id,news_title" instead of "news_items "

Comment: Hmmm what if the second row in News Items table was `27  2  BLAH TICKETING` what should be the result at this situation?

Comment: Which news_id value do you want? 26 or 27? It might not seem to matter to you, since both of your samples have the same `GENERIC TICKETING` news_title value, but the database can't know that. From the DB perspective, those are still _different_ records that both match your join, which only looks at the series_id value.

Comment: OK the join results in 4 rows ..... two rows in table 1...which each have two rows in table 2.

I just need 1 of the rows in table 2 to match up with table 1 "ticket_ordering_temp"

Comment: Then you need to write a join condition that's specific enough it only matches either the 26 news_id row or the 27 news_id row, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sample data and your desired result, you can try following sql to do:

```
SELECT 
    ticket_ordering_temp.*, t.news_title
FROM 
    ticket_ordering_temp    
LEFT JOIN( 
    SELECT DISTINCT series_id, news_title
    FROM news_items
) t ON ticket_ordering_temp.series_id = t.series_id
WHERE temp_id = '58db09bba25b4'
```

however, I think you should tell us the logic behind these sample data.

[**Demo in SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8563ce/1)

Comment: Great answer...thanks I need to disect this when I clear my head a bit.

Answer (score 0):

try this Querying with tempTable:

```
select distinct * from
(select  * from 
(select '58db09bba25b4' as temp_id,   2 as series_id,2 as news_ticket_breakdown_id,2 as quantity,1490750973 as  expiry_time  union all
select '58db09bba25b4' ,  2   ,              4  ,                  1,     1490750973) as tbl_order) as tbl_order

left join


(select series_id,news_title from 
(select  26 as  news_id,         2 as series_id,         'GENERIC TICKETING' as news_title union all
select   27  ,        2 ,        'GENERIC TICKETING') as tbl_items) tbl_items
on tbl_order.series_id = tbl_items.series_id where temp_id ='58db09bba25b4'
```

Querying With actual table:

```
select DISTINCT * from
(select temp_id,series_id,news_ticket_breakdown_id,quantity,expiry_time from tbl_order) as tb_order
left join
(select series_id,news_title from tbl_items) as tb_items
on tb_order.series_id = tb_items.series_id where temp_id ='58db09bba25b4'
```

result:

```
58db09bba25b4   2   2   2   1490750973  2   GENERIC TICKETING
58db09bba25b4   2   4   1   1490750973  2   GENERIC TICKETING
```

Just giving an another solution.